# How to call a Java method from C/C++ with multiple arguments?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Java method with the following signature:

```
public static boolean someMethod(Activity activity, int param1, int param2)
```

How do I call it from C/C++ after getting its `jmethodID`? I know that `CallStaticBooleanMethodV` expects `va_list`, but how do I create it?

Similarly, `CallStaticBooleanMethod` expects an array of `jvalue`, but I unable to create it, e.g. the following does not work:

```
jvalue args[] = {activity, param1, param2};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

> CallStaticMethod Routines CallStaticMethodA Routines
>   CallStaticMethodV Routines NativeType
>   CallStaticMethod(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jmethodID methodID,
>   ...);
>
> NativeType CallStaticMethodA(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
>   jmethodID methodID, jvalue *args);
>
> NativeType CallStaticMethodV(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
>   jmethodID methodID, va_list args);

For your function, the easiest way to call it would be to use the first option( `CallStaticBooleanMethod` ).  Your arguments are just appended to the function call following the class pointer and method id.

```
jobject * instancePtr = NULL;  //assigned to the 
                             //instance of your "Activity" class.
jint param1, param2;  //assign your integer values 
                      //appropriately( jint = int )
jboolean result = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod( myClass, methodID, instancePtr, param1, param2 );
```

You would only need to call the third function( `CallStaticXXXMethodV` ) if you currently already have a variable argument list( i.e. your function is declared `doStuff(...)` ) and you are looking to forward those on.